# when I ssh into RHEL7 AWS-EC2 instance I get 'Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keex,gssapi-with-mic)'

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, rhel7

Ok so I know this question has been asked before.  I tried everything that was posted in the closest related question and none of that worked. I was able to log in before but am not able to now. 
- I have tried ssh-ing in with both `root@ipadress` and `ec2-user@ipaddress` neither have worked.  When I use root it tells me to use ec2-user.  I am ssh-ing from ubuntu 16.04
- I have the correct permissions on my pem file. 
- Also I do not have a `/etc/sshd_special_user` file and not sure that adding one will do anything but it does seem to try to authenticate against my local user after failing the first time.
- When I `ssh-keygen -f " ~/.ssh/known_hosts" -R xx.xx.xxx.xxx` I get `mkstemp: No such file or directory`. I am getting this even thought the file is there and I am able to open it in vim. 
I am really confused as to what is going on here and am going to include the extra verbose log file with this question.  I read through it and am not sure why it is doing what it is doing.

output from `ssh -vvv` is

> -OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
>
> -debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>
> -debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
>
> -debug2: resolving "52.53.159.22" port 22
>
> -debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
>
> -debug1: Connecting to 52.53.159.22 [52.53.159.22] port 22.
>
> -debug1: Connection established.
>
> -debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>
> -debug1: identity file .ssh/RH17-06-11.pem type -1
>
> -debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>
> -debug1: identity file .ssh/RH17-06-11.pem-cert type -1
>
> -debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>
> -debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
>
> -debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
>
> -debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
>
> -debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
>
> -debug1: Authenticating to 52.53.159.22:22 as 'ec2-user'
>
> -debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/dingofarmers/.ssh/known_hosts"
>
> -debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/dingofarmers/.ssh/known_hosts:21
>
> -debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 52.53.159.22
>
> -debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
>
> -debug3: send packet: type 20
>
> -debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>
> -debug3: receive packet: type 20
>
> -debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>
> -debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
>
> -debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
>
> -debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
>
> -debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
>
> -debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
>
> -debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
>
> -debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
>
> -debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
>
> -debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
>
> -debug2: languages ctos:
>
> -debug2: languages stoc:
>
> -debug2: first_kex_follows 0
>
> -debug2: reserved 0
>
> -debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
>
> -debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
>
> -debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
>
> -debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
>
> -debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
>
> -debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
>
> -debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
>
> -debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
>
> -debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
>
> -debug2: languages ctos:
>
> -debug2: languages stoc:
>
> -debug2: first_kex_follows 0
>
> -debug2: reserved 0
>
> -debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
>
> -debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
>
> -debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
>
> -debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
>
> -debug3: send packet: type 30
>
> -debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
>
> -debug3: receive packet: type 31
>
> -debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:qaPtcCft8A+sNZTbFvAsKBPQVvKRqdBYEV93An/SY+w
>
> -debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/dingofarmers/.ssh/known_hosts"
>
> -debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/dingofarmers/.ssh/known_hosts:21
>
> -debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 52.53.159.22
>
> -debug1: Host '52.53.159.22' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
>
> -debug1: Found key in /home/dingofarmers/.ssh/known_hosts:21
>
> -debug3: send packet: type 21
>
> -debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
>
> -debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
>
> -debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>
> -debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>
> -debug3: receive packet: type 21
>
> -debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
>
> -debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
>
> -debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>
> -debug2: key: dingofarmers@ubuntu (0x55ce58f7d660), agent
>
> -debug2: key: dingofarmers@ubuntu (0x55ce58f7e920), agent
>
> -debug2: key: .ssh/RH17-06-11.pem ((nil)), explicit
>
> -debug3: send packet: type 5
>
> -debug3: receive packet: type 6
>
> -debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
>
> -debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>
> -debug3: send packet: type 50
>
> -debug3: receive packet: type 51
>
> -debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
>
> -debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
>
> -debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
>
> -debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
>
> -debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
>
> -debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
>
> -debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
>
> -debug1: No valid Key exchange context
>
> -debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
>
> -debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
>
> -debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
>
> -debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
>
> -debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
>
> -debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information No Kerberos credentials available
>
> -debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information No Kerberos credentials available
>
> -debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
>
> -debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information No Kerberos credentials available
>
> -debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
>
> -debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
>
> -debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
>
> -debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
>
> -debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>
> -debug1: Offering RSA public key: dingofarmers@ubuntu
>
> -debug3: send_pubkey_test
>
> -debug3: send packet: type 50
>
> -debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
>
> -debug3: receive packet: type 51
>
> -debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
>
> -debug1: Offering RSA public key: dingofarmers@ubuntu
>
> -debug3: send_pubkey_test
>
> -debug3: send packet: type 50
>
> -debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
>
> -debug3: receive packet: type 51
>
> -debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
>
> -debug1: Trying private key: .ssh/RH17-06-11.pem
>
> -debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:gwWpJTQxOFvICvYC7ILZ8rTnS9F/TjWaYCmxj6toatY
>
> -debug3: send packet: type 50
>
> -debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
>
> -debug3: receive packet: type 51
>
> -debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
>
> -debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
>
> -debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
>
> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Comment: do you have key.pem file when you created the instance in aws

Comment: yes I have the correct key.pem file and all statuses in aws are green.

Comment: please check the answer below

Comment: Create an AMI from that instance, launch new instance from that AMI (with fresh key) then log in and inspect the logs. If it is not safe to launch another instance like that (due to running services for example), just attach that image volume to another blank instance and inspect logs from there.

Comment: tried a new instance with the old key and another instance with a new key and nither one worked.

Comment: To get rid of Kerberos side-effects, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130952/git-permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-keyex-gssapi-with-mic > even if it does not solve the issue, you will get a clean log.

Comment: I tried this also and got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Move your key file to .ssh directory

`mv path/to/key.pem ~/.ssh/.`

Then make sure you gave right permissions to the file

`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/key.pem`

And connect to server via ssh

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/key.pem ec2-user@instance_ip_address`

Comment: try this
`sudo ssh -i ~/.ssh/key.pem ec2-user@instance_ip_address`

Comment: if adding `sudo` works then check ownership of your key.pem file

Answer (score 0):

The known_hosts file is typically used for recording the system level ssh keys of the servers you're ssh'ing to, not for private key storage. Is there a particular reason you're putting your private key in there? I would probably completely clear the ~/.ssh directories on client and server (making backups first) and start from scratch to keep things simple.

On the client machine, you typically have the ~/.ssh directory (0700 permissions), ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (0600 permissions), and the known hosts file that should be auto-populated each time you ssh into a new system. The actual id_rsa filenames aren't critical of course, as long as the ssh client can find them and parse them, but I've never tried putting their contents inside a file that already means something to ssh.

On the server machine, you would also have the .ssh directory (0700 permissions again), and an authorized_keys file (0600 permissions) that contains the text of the id_rsa.pub key (or equivalent) from the client box.

On the client and server:

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
```

On the client:

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@server.ip:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

On the server:

```
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then try your ssh -vvv again. If that doesn't work run the following command on both client and server and post the results:

```
sudo grep -i key /etc/ssh/ssh*_config
```