# SSH to GitLab Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: linux, git, ssh, permissions, gitlab

I have an issue when I can't ssh to our company GitLab server,
I can easily push, pull, clone repo from this server but when I try to ssh I get an error,
I'm trying to do that on Ubuntu VM and my windows desktop, on both I can do everything except ssh to the server. I can easily ssh to some other servers like Acquia with the same key.
Appreciate any help

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

```
ssh -tvvv gitlab.test-test.com
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "gitlab.test-test.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.test-test.com [111111111] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/oskar/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/oskar/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/oskar/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/oskar/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/oskar/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/oskar/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.test-test.com:22 as 'oskar'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/oskar/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/oskar/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from gitlab.test-test.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: hostkey
SHA256:sha256
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/oskar/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/oskar/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from gitlab.infopro-insight.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/oskar/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/oskar/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 11111111
debug1: Host 'gitlab.test-test.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/oskar/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:SHA256 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)


debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ZrD8RGupQ+Va8QdhqW0sm0bKAcuJIRY1VSDPMuZjzz0 agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/oskar/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
oskar@gitlab.test-test.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Note i changed some unnecessary details for security

Comment: According to the debug output, ssh offered /home/oskar/.ssh/id_rsa to the server and the server didn't accept it. How are you expecting ssh to authenticate to the server? What key is it supposed to use?

Comment: Hmm is it looking for a private key for some reason? In Gitlab account i have added my public SSH key, in folder .ssh/ i have id_rsa which is private key and id_rsa.pub which is public

Comment: Looks similar to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130952/git-permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-keyex-gssapi-with-mic >> check my workaround there

Answer (score 1):

> I can easily push, pull, clone repo from this server

Make sure you can do so using an SSH URL, not an HTTPS one.

If you do use an SSH URL when (successfully) cloning your repository, repeat, for testing, a clone with:

```
git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -Tv" clone git@gitlab.test-test.com:...
```

That will show you what file is actually used.

Don't forget that, contrary to your logs (which shows `oskar@gitlab.test-test.com`), an SSH is always done using the service account `git`, not your own login name.

If you tried `ssh oskar@gitlab.test-test.com`, I confirm it will never work: there is no `oskar` on the remote server, only the technical service account `git` (which, in turn, has an `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` with your GitLab ID associated to your public key: that is how GitLab authenticates you).

Comment: I did tried that, i can see it is using my public key to authenticate with success and it is clonning selected repo to my desktop, althought when i try to do
ssh ssh gitlab.test-test.com
i see an error message 'Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).'

Comment: @Tori it should be `ssh git@gitlab.test-test.com` not `ssh ssh gitlab.test-test.com`